# Is there a standard DateTime string representation that is valid as a Windows file name and can be parsed using DateTime.Parse?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, filenames

As part of a simple backup process, I would like to save files with the name indicating the date and time of the backup. Right now I am using **yyyyMMddTHHmmss**, i.e. "20100601T115720". I would like to be able to parse those dates back to allow clean up of files older than a certain date. (The backup date time is not necessary the same as the file created date.) This ultimately runs in Powershell, using a line something like the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $backupDirectory -filter *.bak | where { [System.DateTime]::ParseExact([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_), "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) -lt $oldestDate }
```

Note that I am currently using the `DateTime.ParseExact` method. This works great, and so I guess my question is more academic, but I'm wondering if there a "standard" Windows file name format that:

- Includes both date and time information AND
- Can be parsed using the standard DateTime.Parse

Comment: Not to be too snarky... but really... is there a standard for anything? ;-)  Just look at how many Date/Time formats there are in general with native storage to SQL vs. UNIX time, etc.

Comment: Nick: In SQL you have a type for that and how it's actually stored is an implementation detail you don't have to worry about (unless it restricts you to dates before 2038, maybe) and how you format it is another matter and up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no "standard" filename format.

I usually use `yyyy-MM-dd, HH-mm-ss`, which is a lot more readable than a blob of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard filename format that I've found, either, but this trick tends to work well for making PowerShell output a localized readable date/time (i.e. February 2nd, 2010 8:15:14 AM):

```
(Get-Date | Out-String).Trim().Replace(":", "-")
```

Piping Get-Date to Out-String uses the default formatter (in this case, the time in the current locale) to make the date a readable string.  Trim() removes the extra newlines from both ends.  Since the only illegal character in the time strings of of the locales I am aware of is ':', I simply replace ':' with '-'

It's most definately a notch slower than using .NET's string formatting.  If you want to use the same trick without using cmdlets, you can write it this way:

```
$date = [DateTime]::Now
($date.ToLongDateString() + " " + $date.ToLongTimeString()).Replace(":",'-')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'd consider unsortable timestamps in filenames not a good idea, though. Anything resembling ISO 8601 should be ok, but not arbitrary other formats, I guess. Especially relying on locale settings for such things is dangerous as it means that your format can change abruptly and you got half of the files in one format, the other half in another.